# Compass removes semicolon when compressing SCSS files, causing issue of CSS importing

Tags: css, gulp, compass, gulp-compass

It is my first time trying out Compass and encountered an issue around how Compass compressed SCSS files.

I had a simple `.scss` file with the following code:

```
@import url('//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

.fa-apple, .fa-android, .fa-twitter {
    font-size: 60px;
}
```

I set up a `Gulp` task to compile the file and here is the task:

```
gulp.task('compass', function() {
    gulp.src('app/scss/style.scss')
        .pipe(compass({
            config_file: './config.rb',
            css: 'app/css',
            sass: 'app/scss',
            require: ['susy', 'breakpoint']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});
```

And this is my `config.rb`:

```
require 'susy'
require 'breakpoint'

project_type = :stand_alone
http_path = "/"
sass_dir = "app/scss"
css_dir = "app/css"
images_dir = "app/images"
fonts_dir = "app/fonts"
javascript_dir = "app/js"
line_comments = true
preferred_syntax = :scss
output_style = :compressed
relative_assets = true
```

So I set the `output_style` to `:compressed` to minified the `CSS` result. This is what I got in the result `css` file:

```
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css").fa-apple,.fa-android,.fa-twitter{font-size:60px}
```

`Compass` removed the ending semicolon of the `@import` statement, which results in unexpected styling on the page.

When I changed `output_style` to `:expanded`, the page worked well with the unminified `css` version as the the semicolon was kept.

Is there a way to avoid `Compass` from removing the semicolon? And also why should it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that newest version (3.4.17 or 3.4.18) of sass is doing this.

Try this:

```
gem uninstall sass
gem install sass -v 3.4.16
```

It worked for me. Here you can find [all versions of sass](https://rubygems.org/gems/sass/versions) if you want to try some other version.

Comment: Great answer! Have wasted so much time on this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this has been [fixed in 3.4.18](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1806).

Comment: Yes, just tested it. Works again in 3.4.18. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't compass be rendering the imported file's code as css?

Comment: No if it is another `css` resource (in the form of a URL) it is importing, I guess.